# KeyError caused by a wrong attribute assignment within the network?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a dataset not well formatted as it has the following columns

```
Source   Target  Label_Source    Label_Target
    E   N   0.0 0.0
    A   B   1.0 1.0
    A   C   1.0 0.0
    A   D   1.0 0.0
    A   N   1.0 0.0
    S   G   0.0 0.0
    S   L   0.0 1.0
    S   C   0.0 0.0
```

Label_Source and Label_Target are nodes attributes Label_Source is a source's attribute while Label_Target is a target's attribute.
Trying to replicate the following project: https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/python-networkx-learning-notes.html, I have encountered some errors, including a KeyError due to Label_Source. As explained in this answer: [KeyError after re-running the (same) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370722/keyerror-after-re-running-the-same-code/70370807?noredirect=1#comment124394924_70370807), the problem seems caused by a wrong assignment in edge/node attributes, as the code is reading Label_Source as edge's attribute.
I would like to replicate the project, as I said, so any format that could make it possible would be acceptable. However, I would really appreciate someone could explain (not only show) how to fix the issue as it is not clear to me what is driving it.
What I have done so far is shown below:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(filtered, 'Source', 'Target',  edge_attr=True)
df_pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k = 0.3) 

nx.draw_networkx(G, df_pos)
plt.show()

node_color = [
    '#1f78b4' if G.nodes[v]["Label_Source"] == 0 # actually this assignment should just Label and it should include also Target, so the whole list of nodes and their labels. A way to address this would be to select all distinct nodes in the network and their labels
    else '#33a02c' for v in G]

# Iterate through all edges
for v, w in G.edges:
    if G.nodes[v]["Label_Source"] == G.nodes[w]["Label_Source"]: # this should refer to all the Labels 
        G.edges[v, w]["internal"] = True
    else:
        G.edges[v, w]["internal"] = False
```

If you could help me to understand how to fix the issue and replicate the code it would be great. I guess the error is also in trying to iterate through strings and not indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the creation of your graph:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(filtered, 'Source', 'Target',  edge_attr=True)
df_pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k = 0.3)
```

You have the following attributes:

```
# For edges:
print(G.edges(data=True))
[('E', 'N', {'Label_Source': 0.0, 'Label_Target': 0.0}),
 ('N', 'A', {'Label_Source': 1.0, 'Label_Target': 0.0}),  # Problem here
 ('A', 'B', {'Label_Source': 1.0, 'Label_Target': 1.0}),
 ('A', 'C', {'Label_Source': 1.0, 'Label_Target': 0.0}),
 ('A', 'D', {'Label_Source': 1.0, 'Label_Target': 0.0}),
 ('C', 'S', {'Label_Source': 0.0, 'Label_Target': 0.0}),
 ('S', 'G', {'Label_Source': 0.0, 'Label_Target': 0.0}),
 ('S', 'L', {'Label_Source': 0.0, 'Label_Target': 1.0})]

# For nodes:
print(G.nodes(data=True))
[('E', {}), ('N', {}), ('A', {}), ('B', {}),
 ('C', {}), ('D', {}), ('S', {}), ('G', {}), ('L', {})]
```

As you can see, nodes have no attribute. You have to copy `Label_xxx` values from edge attributes to right nodes:

```
# Don't use it, check update below
for source, target, attribs in G.edges(data=True):
    G.nodes[source]['Label'] = int(attribs['Label_Source'])
    G.nodes[target]['Label'] = int(attribs['Label_Target'])

print(G.nodes(data=True))
[('E', {'Label': 0}), ('N', {'Label': 1}), ('A', {'Label': 1}),
 ('B', {'Label': 1}), ('C', {'Label': 0}), ('D', {'Label': 0}),
 ('S', {'Label': 0}), ('G', {'Label': 0}), ('L', {'Label': 1})]
```

Now you can set color for each node of your graph:

```
node_color = ['#1f78b4' if v == 0 else '#33a02c'
              for v in nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'Label').values()]

print(node_color)
['#1f78b4', '#33a02c', '#33a02c', '#33a02c',
 '#1f78b4', '#1f78b4', '#1f78b4', '#1f78b4', '#33a02c']
```

Final step:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, df_pos, label=True, node_color=node_color)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update**

> I think there is some problem with the code for assigning the color to nodes. Some nodes have a wrong color (e.g., they should be green and they are blue).

The problem is for the edge `('A', 'N') -> (1, 0)` which is stored as `('N', 'A') -> (1, 0)` because your graph is not directed so it doesn't matter if the edge is `('A', 'N')` or `('N', 'A')`. You can solve this problem by creating your graph with the option `create_using=nx.DiGraph` if that makes sense to your problem.

Another solution is to create the `Label` attribute not from edge attributes but from your dataframe like my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70370110/15239951) suggests:

```
for _, sr in df.iterrows():
    G.nodes[sr['Source']]['Label'] = int(sr['Label_Source'])
    G.nodes[sr['Target']]['Label'] = int(sr['Label_Target'])

print(G.nodes(data=True))
[('E', {'Label': 0}), ('N', {'Label': 0}), ('A', {'Label': 1}),
 ('B', {'Label': 1}), ('C', {'Label': 0}), ('D', {'Label': 0}),
 ('S', {'Label': 0}), ('G', {'Label': 0}), ('L', {'Label': 1})]
```

Now, you have the right `Label` attribute for each node:

[image]

Comment: @LdM. Is it clear for you now?

Comment: Yes you are totally right. I try to understand the internal / external edges

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly the part of internal / external. What is suppose to do?

Comment: from what I have understood from that code, it should identify the nodes that link two (or more) nodes from different classes. Like 'bridge' nodes. Maybe there is a better algorithm to do it. I have not found a lot on the web. I would like to identify nodes that are between two classes

Comment: I think there is some problem with the code for assigning the color to nodes. Some nodes have a wrong color (e.g., they should be green and they are blue)  :(

Comment: I fully understood the error. I will update my answer soon

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please and let me know if some points are not clear.