# KeyError after re-running the (same) code

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

A KeyError is returned when I try to run the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source', 'Target',  edge_attr=True)
df_pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k = 0.3) 

nx.draw_networkx(G, df_pos)
plt.show()

node_color = [
    '#1f78b4' if G.nodes[v]["Label_Source"] == 0 # This returns the error
    else '#33a02c' for v in G]
```

My dataframe has the following columns:

```
Source  Target      Label_Source Label_Target
string1  string2          1           0
string1  string4          1           1
string4  string5          1           0
```

I know that there are many questions on the KeyError name, but what was weird is that without changing anything this error appeared while running the code, but previously I could run the code with no errors. Nothing has changed.
Any help on this would be great!

Traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1266cd6e1844> in <module>
----> 1 node_color = [
      2     '#1f78b4' if G[v]["Label_Source"] == 0
      3     else '#33a02c' for v in G]

<ipython-input-9-1266cd6e1844> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 node_color = [
----> 2     '#1f78b4' if G[v]["Label_Source"] == 0
      3     else '#33a02c' for v in G]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/classes/coreviews.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     49 
     50     def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 51         return self._atlas[key]
     52 
     53     def copy(self):

KeyError: 'Label_Source'
```

Comment: 1) Please post the traceback.  2) This can happen in environments like Jupyter Notebook (or IDEs) where variables remain in scope, when they would otherwise fall out, or when a variable is defined manually while debugging and not manually removed.  Then, once the kernel is restarted, and the script runs ‘naturally’, it exposes variables which were manually defined.

Comment: Hi S3DEV, I will add the traceback. I had already restarted thee kernel, but I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
node_color = np.where(df['Label_Source'] == 0, '#1f78b4', '#33a02c').tolist()
print(node_color)

# Output:
['#33a02c', '#33a02c', '#33a02c']
```

Or using `networkx`:

```
node_color = ['#1f78b4' if v == 0 else '#33a02c'
                  for v in nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'Label_Source')]
print(node_color)

# Output:
['#33a02c', '#33a02c', '#33a02c']
```

Comment: thanks Corralien, it fixes the issue. However, it sees related to the access to nodes v. I will need to keep in that format as I have to access node as follows `for v, w in G.edges:
    if G.nodes[v]["Label_Source"] == G.nodes[w]["Label_Source"]`. This would return the same error :/

Comment: It's not possible: `Label_Source` and `Label_Target` are **not node attributes** but edge ones. You can't access them through the nodes (I think :))

Comment: FYI in case you might be interested in and provide some help, I have opened a bounty for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024111/keyerror-caused-by-a-wrong-attribute-assignment-within-the-network . Since it is related to this post, maybe you might want to have a look at it too